# log error in mysql replication

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I use mysql replication. At slave, i read in aa.err
Statement may not be safe to log in statement format. Statement: update idv_product set visit = visit+1 where id = '173' limit 1
I don`t understad, guide me about error above.

Comment: Please take the time to redact your question in a clear and understandable way.

Answer (score 1):

That error message happens because the statement [relies on the order that the records are stored on disk](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-features-limit.html).  There are a few things you can do to stop the error happening:

1. Use [row-based replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-formats.html) or mixed replication instead of statement based replication.
2. Make sure the field you are using in the WHERE clause is the primary key (I don't think unique keys are enough to stop the error message even though they are adequate to stop the error.)
3. Remove the LIMIT 1 clause from the query.  If `id` is unique then the query will still only update one row.
4. Use an ORDER BY clause on a unique key in the affected queries.  This doesn't make sense for the query you supplied but does for certain other queries that cause this error message.

[Some more reading on this error message.](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42851)